# How to check existence of file in a folder and if missing then get from archive folder in python?

Tags: python

I have created folder where i'm copying 3 source files. I want to check files exist in folder or not? if any file is missing from that folder then print the file name and pick that file from archive folder.

Source files name-

```
File1.xlsx
File2.xlsx
File3.xlsx
```

Archive name -

```
source_files.zip
```

Suppose File2.xlsx is missing in the folder then this file will be pick from archive and copy into that source file folder.

Please help me to implement this logic.

Comment: Did you try any code? Provide that and we can help you on top of that!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I check whether a file exists without exceptions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/82831/how-do-i-check-whether-a-file-exists-without-exceptions)

Answer (score 0):

You're probably best off with a simple `try-except` statement:

```
try:
    # Open File
except IOError:
    # Open Archive File
```

You can find more info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/82831/how-do-i-check-whether-a-file-exists-without-exceptions)

Comment: Edited to catch ioError